# Alert mechanism needed when user clicks the Force stop in android app

Tags: android

I am new to android development and so please apologize if my question is very simple.

I am trying to build an android app which is a location based app, through which users (say Person A) can track another users (say Person B) location continuously.

In app settings, we have an option called 'Force stop'. So from the above case, anytime  Person B can kill my running app using this 'Force stop', so that his location will not be properly monitored by Person A.

I need to avoid this. I have to continuously monitor Person B's location and make him to avoid killing my app using 'Force Stop'. how can I achieve this?

- Is there any way in android to call a particular method (so that I can have some alert code to person A) when Person B clicks the 'Force Stop' button.
- Or is there any way through which, even if Person B stops my app, I can alert the user and restart my app again!

Suggestions please.

Thank You.

Comment: Android is specifically designed not to let applications override user wishes.  The force stop button exists to let the user override a rogue application, which is what (from a platform design perspective) you are proposing to make.  Nor can you prevent the user from doing the smart thing, and uninstalling your app.

Comment: Additionally, an app which has been force stopped is not eligible to automatically start as a result of broadcast receivers, until it is explicitly started again by the user.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I understand what you are trying to explain. However, sorry to ask this again. Iam curious to know whether, can I code some alerting mechanism to alert users when someone clicks the 'Force Stop' button of my app. Apologize if my question is repeating.

Comment: Not directly.  The next time the user willingly and specifically starts your application you might be able to infer that it was abnormally shut down in the past, but you only get to consider this when they have chosen to run your program again.

Comment: The force stop is a kill command - there's nothing you can do to even cleanly clean up resources in that case, much less try to stop it.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Now I am clear. I am little bit worried that I can't even alert my user. However, thanks for your quick response. It helped ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way that user B's app can notify user A that user B clicked "Force Stop", because "Force Stop" brings everything to a halt immediately.

However, user A can infer it if user A's app is expecting regular updates from user B. If user A's app pings user B every minute, and after 1 minute user B's app does not respond, then user A's app can assume that user B's app is "dead". This is probably a better way to do it, anyway. Other things besides "Force Stop" can cause user B's app to be unavailable: user B turns off the device, user B can no longer communicate with user A, Android considers user B's app to be low priority and kills it, user B app crashes because of a bug, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DeviceAdmin api for that. user can't uninstall your application if it enabled as an admin.